# Proper way to update data using setInterval

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, single-page-application, polling

I have an app that fetches data from an external source. Every 5-10mins or so I want to refetch to see if I need to update the app's state.

Is it better to use `setInterval()` with a long timeout (like `300s` or something) and update then, or is it better to poll every like `1s` and then check when the last update was done, fetching the new data if it's been longer than 5mins.

Just curious from a performance standpoint if one is better than the other, I've never really properly implemented this before.

Comment: There's a lot we don't know about the app. How many people will be using it, what kind of server it'll be hosted on and so on. Unless there is there is a hard requirement to see data in "real-time" (1 second or somewhere around there), just stick with setInterval().

Answer (score 2):

Whatever your needs, you generally don't want to use `setInterval` for this, it's slippery road to race conditions (imagine if - for some network quirks - the first setInterval returns *after* the next one). You want to use `setTimeout`:

```
function update() {

  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    // ... do something with your json ...
    setTimeout(update, 1000); // <-- now that this call is done, 
                              //     we can program the next one
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
    setTimeout(update, 1000); // <-- there was a network problem, 
                              //     but still, program the next one!
  });


}

update();
```

This example uses the new Fetch API, but it should make the point in any case.

This said, since you need new data every 5 minutes, just use a long timeout. Instead of 1000, as above, you would use 5 * 60 * 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is better for performance. The second way does 299 unnecessary requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

case 1: It totally depends on your application. see if you have made real time application like fb,whatsapp then it is bad to update on every 3/5 min because user will be notified with delay.

case 2:Suppose you have made app which gives you current temperature then its fine to call it every 3/5 min.
It is totally depend on your application feature.

you can use socket.io.